A movie about mind control experiment by the government?
A man had terrible voices in his head telling him to shoot his own wife with a shotgun.
After a while he couldn't hold himself, grabbed an old shotgun and shot her, only to find that the gun was empty and that she was a government agent experimenting some sort of mind altering device on him.
Another scene that I remember is about the man meeting another guy who had worked in the project (or at least had some connection to it) and that other guy helped him by giving him a cap with a layer made with lead to block the mind control signal from the device.
Oh, and another scene after that is about him, now with the cap, trying to elude a group of agents in an apartment. They used the device and "stalled" the minds of all the residences, and then they started to eject some kind of chips from the back of their heads to analyze their memory. 
More than that I have no idea. I was watching it as I went by in front of my TV.
Does this ring any bell?

Sounds like Control Factor from 2003 with Adam Baldwin and Elizabeth Berkley. From Wiki:

insurance salesman Lance Bishop hears a voice in his head urging him to murder his wife. When he discovers he has become part of a government mind-control project, he and others similarly being experimented on fight back.

He shoots his wife, but it turns out the bullet was a blank and his wife is part of the conspiracy. He also receives a protective cap at some point. The entire movie is currently available on Youtube.
